# itextsharp keeptogether-property on chapter / sections

Tags: itext

Is there any way in iTextSharp to 'keeptogether' chapter/sections, such as PdfpTable and Paragraph?

In my case I have chapters that always contain only one tiny table. If the chaptertitle + the tiny table run out of space I would like to trigger a new page so there is no break in between them.

Thanks for an answer!

Edit:

Here is an example with chapters and paragraphs.
Each chapter has one paragraph.
If the chapter is on the bottom of the page i want it to 'trigger' a new page so that the chapter and the paragraph are always on the same site and not seperatet trough a pagebreak.

```
iTextManager manager = new iTextManager();

manager.NewDocument(PageSize.A4, true, 20,20,20,20);

manager.OpenForOutput(false, true,null);


for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  Chapter c = new Chapter("Chapter " + i, i);
  c.TriggerNewPage = false;
  c.Add(new Paragraph("Paragraph " + i));
  manager.Doc.Add(c);
}


manager.SaveToFile(@"C:\temp\test.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
manager.Close();

Process.Start(@"C:\temp\test.pdf");
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far and describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. There is nothing 'wrong' with it. I just want to know if there is a possibility to get the described behavior. I don't understand the '-1' as well. It was a simple question if a behavior is possible. I don't get why it needs code when the question has all infos needed... But here you go ;)